# Sistema de pontos de lealdade distribiu pontos de forma inesperada | node.js tmi.js

Tags: node.js

Eu estou atualmente a desenvolver um chat bot para o meu canal da twitch.
Quero implementar um sistema de pontos de lealdade que são distribuídos depois de um tempo apenas a quem está presente no chat, para isso eu tenho que verificar se um user entrou ou saiu do chat e mudar os valores que estão armazenados num ficheiro .json. Nesse ficheiro .json estarão armazenados os pontos do user e se ele está no chat ou não.

Este é o código:

```
    let data = fs.readFileSync('./data/data.json');
    let viewer = JSON.parse(data);

    function givePoints(user){
    function intervalFunc() {
    if(viewer[user].online === 1){
    viewer[user].points += 10;
    fs.writeFileSync('./data/data.json', JSON.stringify(viewer, null, 2));
    console.log("+10 Points - " + user);
};
};
setInterval(intervalFunc, 30000);
};

client.on('join', function(channel, user){
    console.log("JOINED:  " + user);

    if(!viewer[user]){
        viewer[user] = {
            online: 1,
            points: 0
        };
    };

    viewer[user].online = 1;            
    fs.writeFileSync('./data/data.json', JSON.stringify(viewer, null, 2));

    givePoints(user);
});

client.on('part', function(channel, user){
    console.log("PARTED:  " + user);
    viewer[user].online = 0;
    fs.writeFileSync('./data/data.json', JSON.stringify(viewer, null, 2));
});
```

Este é o .json:

```
    {
  "streamelements": {
    "online": 0,
    "points": 0
  },
  "jptron": {
    "online": 0,
    "points": 0
  }
}
```

O programa detecta com sucesso se o user existe no .json e se deu *join* ou *part*.
O problema é quando alguém sai do chat e volta a entrar. Quando isso acontece o programa distribui os pontos a esse user mais vezes do que deveria.

Eu adicionei um console.log sempre que o bot distribui os pontos:
[image: Logs dos pontos]
O user *streamelements* é um outro bot conectado ao meu canal.

Gostaria de saber o que eu poderia estar alterando no meu código para este funcionar da maneira pretendida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando o usuário entra vc dispara a função setInterval, porém quado o usuário sai vc não cancela ela.

O que acontece é que o cliente entra, antes de dar o tempo ele sai e entra de novo. Assim ele vai ficar com 2 timers associados a ele. Quando atingir o tempo do primeiro timer ele ganha os pontos, quando atingir o tempo do segundo ele ganha de novo.

Penso em 2 opçoes:

1. Salve a variável de cada setInterval dos usuários e de um clearInterval quando o usuário sair.
2. Salve no seu json a data da ultima entrada e além da validação se o cliente está online na intervalFunc valide quanto tempo passou, se for menor que o timer configurado não conceda os pontos.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Não sei o porquê de não ter pensado nisso antes, adicionei um clearInterval à função e está trabalhando direitinho.